# magento observer not firing xml is in order

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.9

Not sure what is wrong.
Have been writing custom extensions for our shops. First wrote one extension which observed checkout_onepage_controller_success_action

it was working fine.

added second extension which also observe same event, the second extension didn't called the function.

combined 2 extensions in to 1 and it did the trick, but now i have third extension with same event, again it doesn't fire the function.

removed other 2 extensions to keep the new one i just created with observer for checkout_onepage_controller_success_action still my function is not being executed.

not really sure what is wrong.

xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
  <modules>
    <Wemessage_Easytrans>
      <version>1.0.0</version>
    </Wemessage_Easytrans>
  </modules>
  <global>
    <helpers>
      <easytrans>
        <class>Wemessage_Easytrans_Helper</class>
      </easytrans>
    </helpers>
    <models>
      <easytrans>
        <class>Wemessage_Easytrans_Model</class>
        <resourceModel>easytrans_mysql4</resourceModel>
      </easytrans>
    </models>
    <events>
      <checkout_onepage_controller_success_action> <!-- identifier of the event we want to catch -->
        <observers>
          <checkout_onepage_controller_success_action_handler> <!-- identifier of the event handler -->
            <type>model</type> <!-- class method call type; valid are model, object and singleton -->
            <class>Wemessage_Easytrans_Model_Observer</class> <!-- observers class alias -->
            <method>sendToEasyTrans</method>  <!-- observer's method to be called -->
            <args></args> <!-- additional arguments passed to observer -->
          </checkout_onepage_controller_success_action_handler>
        </observers>
      </checkout_onepage_controller_success_action>
    </events>
  </global>
</config>
```

php:

```
<?php
class Wemessage_Easytrans_Model_Observer
{
    public function sendToEasyTrans(Varien_Event_Observer $observer){
        $order_ids = $observer->getEvent()->getOrderIds();
        $order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->load($order_ids[0]);
        $shippingAddress = $order->getShippingAddress();
        var_dump($shippingAddress->getData());
        die;
        // removed some code since it will be very long to paste here
    }
}
```

so basically code have to dump some data for me and stop there.
but i don't see any data nor the white screen of death.

i do see extension in backend as active one since have added some system configuration options to backend

Comment: It's working, I just check it by copy/pasting your code in my instance where already multiple observers are running on the same event. Plz check your folders and files naming carefully.

Comment: checked, still same if i change it to another observer it does work. so dicided to stick with sales_order_place_after but not sure if it's fired only once.

Answer (score 0):

The event checkout_onepage_controller_success_action only have one object to get: $order.

You're trying to get a $orderIds object that does not exist. That's why you receive an empty object:

```
    $order_ids = $observer->getEvent()->getOrderIds()

    $order = $observer->getEvent()->getOrder();
```

To get several orders you may get them by other way.

Regards.